# Update value after the first condition is met and if there is a duplicate mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm looking into creating a column Status based on a football result where if you have the maximum points, then you're the champion. However, if there are two teams with the maximum points, then another condition where goal differences need to be the highest as well to be the champion. The status will display as '1' if the team is a champion and '0' otherwise.

An example of my original table is as follow:

| Team | Total_points | Goal_difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | 3 |
| B | 20 | 2 |
| C | 20 | 5 |
| D | 10 | 9 |

Afterwards, I'd insert another column called status, and update it based on the total_points only:

```
alter table_name
add column status int(1) after goal_difference;

update table_name
set status = case
    when total_points = (select * from (select max(total_points) from table_name) as X) then '1'
    else '0'
end;
```

How can I modify my command so that if the first condition is satisfied and only when duplicate values of '1' is detected, it will then proceed to check the conditions of the goal difference? The priority is still the total points not the goal difference.

Any feedback is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just to observe, your 'table' would normally be the result of a query against a data set comprising match results.

Comment: yes, it is indeed a result of multiple queries that are used to pull data from other table

Comment: Well in that case, I can't see why you'd be updating anything. Incidentally, here's an ancient thread on a related subject... https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,224289,224407#msg-224407

Comment: Oh, it's great to know why certain procedure shouldn't be updated. However, for my case, I'm only doing this as a practice and self-study of MySQL so I don't have too many concerns regarding updating the table, as all data isn't going to be updated and all I want to do is getting better at writing queries to obtain the result that I want with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` would work well here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Total_points DESC, Goal_difference DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Team, Total_points, Goal_difference,
       CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS champion
FROM cte
ORDER BY Team, rn;
```

Comment: I tried running the update command by setting the status = select champion from (this command); the error returns as 1242. What is the possible reason? As from my understanding, the update command should allow a column to be updated with a select command that returns a column provided that both columns have the same length

Comment: @DavieJohn I suggest _not_ doing this update, because the winner may change any time that data be added or deleted from your table.  Instead, consider just putting my query above into a view.

Comment: Oh ok, great to know the real life application. As I'm only doing this as a side project that I picked up using any open source data that I can have access to. All the data is not updated anymore and is from past data